# Playing DVD's Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, dvd

I can play DVD's in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr, but only once.  If I want to play another DVD, I have to restart my system.  OK, I've figured this part out.  I have to click on File>Eject in Totem, then I can play another DVD.  However, I have 2 DVD's when inserted, simply bring up a folder with only 1 file in it named "VIDEO_TS", & won't play.  I've installed libdvdread4, libdvdnav4, libdvdcss2, and have executed sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh.  When I run sudo regionset in terminal, I get this:

regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on DVD drives
ERROR: Could not open disc "(null)"!
Please ensure there is a readable CD or DVD in the drive.

Is there another package that I need to install?  I want to be able to play ALL DVD's.